# latexdiff problem when adding section and changing first sentence of new section

Tags: latexdiff

Consider this example, which I'll call `temp1.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Some section}
This is an arbitrary sentence. 
And this is another arbitrary sentence. 
\end{document}
```

and this revision of it, which I'll call `temp2.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Some section}
Hello there. 
\section{Some new section}
And this is another arbitrary sentence.
\end{document}
```

The only thing I've done is adding a new section. Here's what

```
latexdiff -t CFONT temp1.tex temp2.tex > diff.tex 
pdflatex diff
```

gives:

[image]

So far so good. Now consider this variation of `temp2.tex` (`here` instead of `this` as the second word of the new section):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Some section}
This is an arbitrary sentence. 
\section{Some new section}
And here is another arbitrary sentence. 
\end{document}
```

Now I get

[image]

It seems that `latexdiff` gets confused by the simultaneous change of a sentence being moved into a new section and that sentence being changed. I would have expected the word change to have resulted in:

[image]

How can I get `latexdiff` to behave as I expected?

Comment: Have you tried the different `latexdiff` variants? That is, `latexdiff-so` vs. `latexdiff-vc`? That sometimes gives a different result because of the different algorithm it uses to determine the differences.

Comment: @Tony: `latexdiff-vc` gives the same result. `latexdiff-so` doesn't seem to be installed on my system.

Comment: This is a  side-effect of another constraint that tries to avoid interleaving changed paragraphs. You can change this behaviour with the option `--config MINWORDSBLOCK=1` which I expect will give you the desired behaviour (no time to test unfortunately) but will give poor results in case you exchange one paragraph for another (or likely even one sentence for another).